# Create columns with match inside range from different dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range

I got two dataframes with several columns but with these three with similar data.

```
Df1:
ID         Line    ...      Sta
19805       120    ...       30
19805       120    ...       40
19805       123    ...       30
    .       .       .         .
    .       .       .         .
19841       120    ...        30

Df2:
 ID         Line     ...      Sta
19805       122      ...       30
19805       119      ...       41
19805       123      ...       30
    .        .       .          .
    .        .       .          .
19841        120      ...      33
```

I would like to add two columns to Df2 with the same columns of Df1 using the nearest match to Df1

```
Df2:
 ID         Line     ...      Sta   linedf1   stadf1
19805       122      ...       30      120        30
19805       119      ...       41      120        40
19805       123      ...       30      123        30
    .        .        .         .       .         .
    .        .        .         .       .         .
19841        120      ...      33       120       30
```

note that the match is needed to be inside a range of Df2["Line"]+-4 and Df2["Sta"]+-4

So I tried this:

```
Df1["line"].where((Df2['line']-4)<=Df1["line"]) & (Df1["line"]<=(Df2['line']+4)

Df1.loc[((Df2['line']-4)<=Df1["line"]) & ((Df1["line"]<=(Df2['line']+4))]

Df1[Df1["line"].between((Df2['line']-4),(Df2['line']+4), inclusive= True)]
```

but all of them result in this error

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Any one have any idea how to achieve this?
hope this question is not too vague

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) first:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on='ID', suffixes=('', 'df1'))
df = df[df["Line"].between((df['Linedf1']-4),(df['Linedf1']+4), inclusive= True)]
print (df)
      ID  Line  Sta  Linedf1  Stadf1
0  19805   122   30      120      30
1  19805   122   30      120      40
2  19805   122   30      123      30
3  19805   119   41      120      30
4  19805   119   41      120      40
5  19805   119   41      123      30
6  19805   123   30      120      30
7  19805   123   30      120      40
8  19805   123   30      123      30
9  19841   120   33      120      30
```

One possible solution is processing in chunks, by each N rows, create liest of DataFrames and last concat together:

```
#change to 10000 or 100000 in real data
N = 3
dfs = []
for g, df11 in df1.groupby(np.arange(len(df1.index)) // N):
    df = df2.merge(df11, on='ID', suffixes=('', 'df1'))
    df = df[df["Line"].between((df['Linedf1']-4),(df['Linedf1']+4), inclusive= True)]
    #print (df)
    dfs.append(df)

dfout = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (dfout)
      ID  Line  Sta  Linedf1  Stadf1
0  19805   122   30      120      30
1  19805   122   30      120      40
2  19805   122   30      123      30
3  19805   119   41      120      30
4  19805   119   41      120      40
5  19805   119   41      123      30
6  19805   123   30      120      30
7  19805   123   30      120      40
8  19805   123   30      123      30
9  19841   120   33      120      30
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Unfortunately this didn't work due to RAM memory limitations. Both Df1 and Df2 are large dataframes (df1 have 800k rows and df2  300k) and when trying this merge exceeded the RAM memory allowed in google's colab notebook  (24 gb, much more than the 4gb of RAM in my laptop).  What I need is to improve the merge between these DF. I have merged these DF with exact match on "ID", "line" and "sta" but this only results in a 40% of exact match, therefor the need for the  matching with ranges.

Comment: @Rubén - I have one idea, answer was edited. Can you test it with your real data?

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, I actually had to install a SQL manager to do it (and ask another SQL expert for it).